# Close UIView when UIButton is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my app I have a Horizontal Image Gallery wherein when I tap the image, `UIView` is called displaying enlarged images. The `UIView` contains, a `scrollView`, `imageviews` (dynamically created) and a `UIButton` (close button) programmatically created. However, when I tap the close button `UIView` is not dismissed.
In my **viewDidLoad** I set up the `gestureRecognizer`.

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapAction:)]];
```

Here's my **singleTapAction** method:

```
- (void)singleTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)singleTap_
{
    MTGalleryPopUp* galleryImage = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MTGalleryPopUp" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    if(galleryImage.hidden)
    {
        NSLog(@"HIDDEN");
        [galleryImage dismissWithAnimation:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NOT HIDDEN");
        [self showGalleryDialog];
    }
}
```

Here's my **showGalleryDialog** method:

```
- (void)showGalleryDialog
{
    MTGalleryPopUp * galleryView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MTGalleryPopUp" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    [galleryView setReferenceVC:self];
    [galleryView initWithTitle:@"Image Gallery"];
    [galleryView setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.view addSubview:galleryView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [galleryView setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Here's how i am creating the `UIView`:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // portrait bounds
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect])
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f]];

        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, TITLE_HEIGHT, screenRect.size.width, 350)];
        [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

       CloseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       [CloseButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(dismissWithAnimation:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [CloseButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [CloseButton.layer setBorderWidth:2];
        [CloseButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

        CloseButton.layer.cornerRadius=10;
        CloseButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [CloseButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CloseButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
        CloseButton.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-80, 8, 20, 20);
        [self addSubview:CloseButton];

        strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?temp_url_sig=%@&temp_url_expires=%lld", URLstorage, CONTAINER_PATH, HMACStr, [@(floor([oneMinLater timeIntervalSince1970])) longLongValue]];

        [mutableURLstorage addObject:strURL];
        [imagesArray addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]]]];
    }

    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(ITEM_WIDTH, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    _pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height-30, 320, 36)];
    _pgCtr.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    int numberofPage=ceil((float)[imagesArray count]/2.5);
    _pgCtr.numberOfPages= numberofPage;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(450*numberofPage, pageSize.height);

    int imgCurrentX = 10;
    for (UIImageView* image in imagesArray)
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgCurrentX, 45, 200, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 10)];
                imageview.image = (UIImage*)image;
                [imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                [self.scrollView addSubview:imageview];
                imgCurrentX = imgCurrentX + 220;
            }
        }

        [self addSubview:self.scrollView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I'm on debug, what happens is it goes back to singleTap_ method and recreates again the `UIView` (now two `UIViews` are overlapping). What am I doing wrong here?

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to show and hide one view on tap, Im right ?

Comment: @PravinTate yep..I tried everything. -_-

Comment: do you need code for show and hide uiview on button click, right

Comment: @PravinTate not really..what I need is code for hiding the uiview. I am able to show the UIView when the image is tapped..

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems: MTGalleryPopUp is not saved; the view is not init properly; i think you dismiss view by changing 'alpha', but check 'hidden' property in singleTapAction: - it is different things.

Add property galleryPopUp to the root controller:

```
@property MTGalleryPopUp *galleryPopUp;
```

It'll be a lazy initialisation object, add this method:

```
- (MTGalleryPopUp *)galleryPopUp {
  if (!_galleryPopUp) {
    _galleryPopUp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MTGalleryPopUp" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
  }
  return _galleryPopUp;
}
```

Change singleTapAction:

```
- (void)singleTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)singleTap_
{
    if(self.galleryPopUp.alpa == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"HIDDEN");
        [self showGalleryDialog];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NOT HIDDEN");
        [galleryImage dismissWithAnimation:YES];
    }
}
```

And there is a problem in showGalleryDialog:

```
[galleryView initWithTitle:@"Image Gallery"];
```

It should be called in UIView, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, I tried that earlier. if i do that it doesnt display the UIView at all. hmmm, I have a question, how can I set a uiview to hidden. i think when i run the app the uiview.hidden is true.

Comment: Are MTGalleryPopUp and the "UIView" the same?

Comment: No bye default uiview is hidden false so change Ur code

Answer (score 0):

You are created two objects of "MTGalleryPopUp" class. So better way is declare it in  ".h" file and initilise it  in viewDidLoad. As per tap just hide and show. I hope it will solve your problem